# AngularJS Filed nested array of objects with array of objects

Tags: angularjs, arrays, object, filter, compare

I'm trying to filter a nested array of objects with my own objects, by idSubject. But I'm not getting the right result.

I have articles (which have subjects)
And a array of objects (which are the subjects I want to filter the articles with)

Data looks like this:

[image]

[image]

So I'm trying to filter the array of articles by its subjects.

I tried the following:

```
<div class="panel panel-default"
                     ng-repeat="searchArticle in searchArticles | filter: {subjects: filterSubjects} as articleSearchResult">
```

So filterSubjects is the second screenshot and SearchArticles is the first screenshot.

Without much luck.

Hope you can help, please tell me if things are still unclear.

Comment: You will need to create a custom filter for this and do the matching yourself

Comment: @charlietfl Any example?. I tried this a couple of times but failed.

Comment: Are all the name values unique? If so I would make an object that uses those values as keys and then in the filtering check if that property exists when you iterate main array

Comment: @charlietfl No. Only the idSubject. This is also the only property I want to filter. There are checkboxes which I want to be able to check and then filter the subjects of the articles. The idSubject is unique.

Comment: Same principle then ... extract all the ID's from `filterSubjects` then check when you iterate `searchArticles `

Comment: @charlietfl Can you make an example? Would be nice. I can mark it as the correct answer if it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This custom filter will help you.

Example : http://plnkr.co/edit/jMizCLxPH6DtDA5wL15Q?p=preview

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<h2>Select Subjects</h2>
    <div ng-repeat="subject in subjects">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filterSubjects[subject.id]" ng-true-value="'{{subject.id}}'" ng-false-value="''">{{subject.name}}</label>
    </div>

    <h2>Filtered Articles</h2>

    <div ng-repeat="searchArticle in searchArticles | subjectFilter:filterSubjects">{{searchArticle.name}}</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.searchArticles = [{
    "name": "Article1",
    "sid": "1"
  }, {
    "name": "Article2",
    "sid": "1"
  }, {
    "name": "Article3",
    "sid": "2"
  }];
  $scope.subjects = [{
    "name": "Subject1",
    "id": "1"
  }, {
    "name": "Subject2",
    "id": "2"
  }];
  $scope.filterSubjects = [];

});

app.filter('subjectFilter', function() {
  return function(articles, filterSubjects) {
    filtered = articles.filter(function(e){return filterSubjects.indexOf(e.sid) >= 0},filterSubjects);
    return filtered;
  }
});
```

if you want to filter based on object :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.searchArticles = [{
    "name": "Article1",
    "sid": "1"
  }, {
    "name": "Article2",
    "sid": "1"
  }, {
    "name": "Article3",
    "sid": "2"
  }];
  $scope.subjects = [{
    "name": "Subject1",
    "id": "1"
  }, {
    "name": "Subject2",
    "id": "2"
  }];
  $scope.filterSubjects = [{
    "name": "Subject1",
    "id": "1"
  }, {
    "name": "Subject1",
    "id": "2"
  }];

});

app.filter('subjectFilter', function() {
  return function(articles, filterSubjects) {
    var sFiltered = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < filterSubjects.length; i++) {
      sFiltered.push(filterSubjects[i].id);
    }
    var filtered = articles.filter(function(e) {
      return sFiltered.indexOf(e.sid) >= 0;
    }, sFiltered);
    return filtered;
  }
});
```

Comment: It gets me in the right direction, but your data modal has a sid and not an array of objects like mine. How would I do it with the array of objects? Thanks for replying.

Comment: @TVH7 you are telling about filterSubjects will be array of object , if it is like this you want to write the loop to find the matching one.

Comment: filterSubjects is indeed an array of 'subjects', an article has an array of subject objects too. So I want to filter articles by the array of subjects. Lets say I select subject 1 and 2, then I only want to see articles with subject 1 and 2 in its array of objects.

Comment: @TVH7 i had updated my answer for your object filter condition, if it is not helping, you can create one example show your problem so i can help you out.